# updating rails 4.2.5 to rails 5, keep having ActiveModel dependencies issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

when updating a rails 4.2.5 app (thats in production on heroku) to rails 5, i keep running into the below incompatible version for the gem, i've tried the bundle update, bundle install, done everything asked by the upgrade docs on rails site and stackoverflow.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
   In snapshot (Gemfile.lock):
     activemodel (= 5.0.0)

   In Gemfile:
     active_model-errors_details was resolved to 1.3.0, which depends 
 on
      activemodel (< 5.0.0.beta1, >= 3.2.13)

     carrierwave was resolved to 1.2.2, which depends on
       activemodel (>= 4.0.0)

     rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
       activemodel (= 5.0.0)

     web-console (~> 2.0) was resolved to 2.3.0, which depends on
       activemodel (>= 4.0)

   Running `bundle update` will rebuild your snapshot from scratch, 
 using only
 the gems in your Gemfile, which may resolve the conflict.
```

Comment: The issue is with `active_model-errors_details`. It depends on less than `5.0.0.beta1` but your version of `5.0.0` is greater than that. Either update `active_model-errors_details` to a version which supports rails 5.0.0 (not beta) or remove it

Answer (score 1):

There is no version of the `active_model-errors_details` that supports Ruby on Rails `5.x` (see its [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/gems/active_model-errors_details) page).

But the [documentation](https://github.com/cowbell/active_model-errors_details) of the `active_model-errors_details` says that it is a *feature backported from Rails 5.0 to use with Rails 3.2.x and 4.x apps*.

Therefore I think there is no need to keep that gem in your application once you update to Ruby 5.0. Just remove the `gem 'active_model-errors_details'` line from your `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` again.